# Calculating a pdf with uncertain limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Say we have a random vector $(X,Y)$ with the joint pdf $f(x,y)=1/a$ where $(x,y)$ belongs to $(0,1) \times (x,x+a)$. What would be correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$.   I'm asked to analyze what happens to the correlation coefficients as $a \to 0$ and $a \to \infty$?

We know the formula of the correlation coefficients is $Cov(X,Y)/\sigma_{x} \sigma_{y}$.  $Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$.  So to find $E[X]$, $E[Y]$ and $E[X]E[Y]$, we would just take the integral
\begin{equation} \int_0^1 \int_x^{x+a} \frac{1}{a} \, dy \, dx \end{equation}
So since I'm more interested in the behavior of the correlation coefficient, we just look at the top.  When $a \to 0$ then you have the integral collapsing into 0, right?  But when $a \to \infty$, you can't really subtract infinity with infinity, can you?  How would you tackle this part and has my reasoning been sound so far?

Comment: **Imagine** calculating. The means can be read off, but we will need $E(X^2)$, $E(Y^2)$, $E(XY)$. These are double integrals *like* the one you mention, but the functions will be $x^2/a$ and so on. The correlation coefficient will presumably involve $a$ both on **top and bottom**.   What about if we don't calculate? If $a$ is close to $0$, then it seems clear that the correlation coefficient will be close to  $1$. And it seems almost as clear that the correlation coefficient is near $0$ when $a$ is large.

Answer (score 1):

So, while you're correct in saying $\lim_{x \to \infty} f$ - $\lim_{x \to \infty} g$ is meaningless when they both go off to infinity, you're missing a bunch of things:

1. If $f$ and $g$ both go to infinity, this goes not mean that $\lim (f-g) = \infty$ as well. As an  example, take $f(x) = x$, and $g(x) = x - 1$.
2. Note that you're also dividing by $\sigma_y$ which itself goes to infinity with $a$. So there's a second reason that the correlation may converge.
3. Lastly, recall that the correlation coefficient is bounded! $ |\rho| \le 1$.

<s>I'm afraid there's no real shortcut for the $a \to \infty$ case, you'll simply have to calculate the coefficient.</s>

Edit: I'm embarrassingly inaccurate in saying that there's no shortcut. The way I intended to put it was: the shortcut to the $a \to \infty $ is less driven by technical issues and way more by an intuitive picture of what's happening. If that is something you haven't formed yet, doing the calculations should help you form it, once the answer pops out and you think about it.

---

Edit 2: I'm guessing OP is a bit unfamiliar with this method, and hence posting a (partial) solution:

It's easy to see that $\mathbb{E}[Y~|X] = X + \frac{a}{2}$, as $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $[X, X+a]$. Now,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[XY] &= \mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[Y~|X]] = \mathbb{E}[X^2 + aX/2]\\
&= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{a}{4}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y] &= \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[Y ~|X] ] = \mathbb{E}[X + a/2]\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{a}{2}
\end{align}

Consequently,

$$Cov(X,Y) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{a}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \times \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{a}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{12}$$

Now try calculating the variance of $Y$.

Comment: I calculated this correlation coefficient by hand and the result I got was ((1/3a+1/4)-(1+a)/4)/(1/12(1/3a(a^3+1.5a^2+a)-1/2a(-a(a+1))^2+1/4a(a+1)^3).  How can you see from this mess that as a tends to infinity the limit is 0 and as a tends to 0 the limit is 4?

Comment: You might want to check your calculations. Far as I see, $Cov(X, Y) = 1/12$, always. $\sigma_y$ blows up as $a \to \infty$. Ergo, the correlation goes to zero. The $a \to 0$ case is much easier to picture.

Comment: A useful technique here is using $\mathbb{E}[ XY] = \mathbb{E} [ \mathbb{E} [XY ~|X] ] = \mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[Y~|X] ]$

Comment: How do you use the "useful technique" above?  And how can Cov(X,Y)=1/12 when you have the variable a to deal with?

Comment: @cambelot See the edit.